# Perforce: How to integrate across multiple branches

Tags: branch, perforce, branching-and-merging

For a new feature I'm implementing, I'm looking to set up the following branches in a Perforce respository: branch A, which is the main branch, and branch B and C, both branched from A at the same time.

All branches will be worked on in parallel. Branch B will be integrated frequently into branch C, and occasionally into branch A.
To ensure branch B and C don't fall too far behind branch A, branch A will occasionaly be integrated into B and C.

Once the work on branch B is finished, it will be integrated to both A and C one last time, and work will continue on branch C.

Eventually, once all the work on branch C is finished, it will be integrated into branch A.

My question is: Will there be any issues integrating branch A into C and C into A in regards to the changes made in branch B, or will perforce "remember" that both branches have changes integrated from branch B?

I found this related question on a different forum mentioning this is not possible, but it's 25 years old, so I'm hoping somethings changed since then:
https://perforce-user.perforce.narkive.com/8Hfcadpb/three-way-merge-and-reverse-integration

The reason I need a setup like this is because branch C will contain confidential code that can't go into the main branch A until the feature is finished. Branch B will contain code relevant to the feature in C, but not confidential, and so it can be integrated into branch A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be fine.

Merging tends to be less confusing when all integrations happen between parent and child (so in this example, A<->B and A<->C), but if you do trickier things, Perforce does lots of tricky math behind the scenes to figure out how to integrate all the outstanding changes and it usually works fine without you having to think too hard about it.

Given the workflow you describe, FWIW, I would probably set up the branches such that C is a child of B:

```
A----------------------------------------
   \   \     \ /    \  /   \  \     /
    B------------------     \  \   /
     \ \ \ \ \ \  \  \ \     \  \ /
      C---------------------------
```

i.e. C receives A's changes via B for as long as B is active and contributing its own changes to C.  After B hits its end of life and stops adding its own changes, *then* it makes sense to cut it out of the workflow and start merging directly between A and C.

My intuition is that this will make for simpler merges (during that initial phase where three branches are active at once) because the changes you're merging from B will already contain the work you did to resolve A vs B; if you go directly from A to C, you might end up having to re-resolve the same changes twice in slightly different contexts.  (Again, Perforce does tricky math to try to make complicated scenarios work as simply as possible, and in many cases it should be able to help you avoid that type of redundant work through clever merge base selection, but if nothing else I think it's easier to reason about as an end user when the relationships are simpler to start with).